# Difference and suggest ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I want to know the main difference between ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and ThreadPoolExecutor. Which one should i choose and why?

Comment: Start from their respective Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at documentation link to understand the differences clearly.

[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

> An ExecutorService that executes each submitted task using one of possibly several pooled threads, normally configured using Executors factory methods.

Thread pools address two different problems: they usually provide improved performance when executing large numbers of asynchronous tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead, and they provide a means of bounding and managing the resources, including threads, consumed when executing a collection of tasks.

[ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html)

JavaBean that allows for configuring a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in bean style (through its "**corePoolSize**", "**maxPoolSize**", "**keepAliveSeconds**", "**queueCapacity**" properties) and exposing it as a Spring **TaskExecutor**.

This class is also well suited for management and monitoring (e.g. through JMX), providing several useful attributes: "*corePoolSize*", "*maxPoolSize*", "*keepAliveSeconds*" (all supporting updates at runtime); "*poolSize*", "*activeCount*" (for introspection only).

Answer (score 0):

They're basically identical in terms of functionality.  The difference is whether you want to initialise it through a constructor (recommended if created in Java code) or through setters (recommend if created in Spring).